# How to reshape my nupy array, to make a valid prediction in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

i trained my n-network, and everything work fine, except that i don't know how to format my data to make a prediction on data that are not in training and testing set.

- I loaded csv data.
- I split it into training and testing set,
  and everything fork fine
  for

  ```
         x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
  ```

  bestmodel.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=5)  i got like 97% acc.
  For

  print(type(x_test))
   print(x_test.dtype)
   print(x_test.shape)

i have output like

```
 class 
'numpy.ndarray'
float64
(905, 14)
```

i made my own example,

```
 z = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]).astype(float)

    np.reshape(z, (14,))
```

but when i try

```
bestmodel.predict(z)
```

i got error

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/BankMarketinData/main.py", line 81, in 
    main()
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/BankMarketinData/main.py", line 76, in main
    score = bestmodel.predict(z)
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Can you help me reshape and format this z table, that i can use it for prediciton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the batch dimension with a value of 1:

```
z = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]).astype(float)
# z.shape is (14,)
z = np.expand_dims(z, axis=0)
# z.shape is now (1, 14)

bestmodel.predict(z)
```